# How to prevent string parameters sent to database from keep getting whitespace trimmed?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using prepared statements to load my database with various small strings, and it appears java is automatically trimming them.  When I attempt to load a value of " " (a single space), it ends up as a blank string in the database.  Multiple spaces have the same result, so it appears to be trimming.

I don't call any .trim() on the text, I simply have this:

```
cmd.setString(3, " ");
```

to load one of my parameters.  Otherwise, everything works fine, it is only whitespace that appears to have any problems.  Since I'm making many queries in a sequence, I must used a prepared statement or else the inefficiency is too great, so I can't just manually load up sql statements.

Is there some option somewhere to turn this off?  Or a workaround of some kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification of java.sql doesn't establish that the driver must do a trim() operation. But just in case could you try the following?

```
 cmd.setNString(3, " ");
```

Comment: setNString also, unfortunately, results in a blank string

Comment: I have checked the source code of PreparedStatement of Connector/J and there is no a invocation for trim() function. So maybe there is another error that we aren't seeing.

Comment: Well, it is loading into a CHAR(1) field, and it worked properly with the .net connector.  There's really not anything else to look at, so I'm not sure where the problem is originating...

Comment: Oddly, newlines are entered fine.  But multiple spaces turn into a blank string...

Comment: I don't see a setChar, but it's fine now.  Thanks for the help, but it seems like it's something odd about how connector/j deals with a CHAR field.  I tried switching the field to VARCHAR(1), and now the space is entered.  I have no idea why it makes a difference.

Comment: The problem AFAIK is that either MySQL or the MySQL Connector/J driver misinterprets SQL standards regarding the CHAR datatype and trims whitespace instead of returning the full length of the field (padded with spaces) as required by the SQL standards.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this.

```
String s= new String(" ");
cmd.setBytes(3,s.getBytes(s));
```

check if that help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when calling stored procedure in mysql. But it turns out if you run this from mysql:

```
select '  ' = '';
```

It returns (1) true.

So, my stored procedure was reporting back as empty string, but the stored procedure did get the string with spaces.

To fix, I had to check for empty string using LIKE or check if char length is 0.